# How to cite electronic resources using achemso package and bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, achemso

I'm preparing a paper for an American Chemical Society journal, hence using the `achemso` document class and bibliography style, along with `bibtex`.   Accordingly I don't want to change the `achemso` style file at all.

1. What's the correct item type to use for an electronic resource?  I've tried `url`, `electronic`, and `webpage` (options available in bibdesk) but none are recognized upon compiling with `bibtex`.  (it seems to fall back to `misc`)
2. What would the correct field be for including the Last Accessed date - again, the `urldate` field does not seem to be recognized in the `achemso` style.

Comment: The `biblatex-chem` package defines  a `chem-acs` style. With biblatex, electronic resources correspond to the `@online`  entry type.

Comment: If you want to submit to a journal of the ACS I would *not* use `biblatex-chem` (unless you cleared this with the editor), it seems safer to stick to `achemso` and its `achemso.bst` BibTeX style. With that style the only type that supports URLs is `@misc` (you could use a different undefined type like `@online` or `@electronic`, but it will fall back to `@misc` as you say, so you don't gain a lot). There is no field for the URL access date, you could put it into the `note` field. (I'd check with the ACS if an access date is needed at all.)

Comment: @moewe - Agreed, I need to stick with `bibtex` to make it easy with the journal.  Thanks for the confirmation that I feared that I can't really do it "the right way".   Thanks for the idea about the `note` field too.

Comment: The CTAN page says that `achemso` bundles the *official* class and BibTeX styles (https://ctan.org/pkg/achemso) so unless you have hard proof of the contrary I would just assume that the BibTeX styles produce the desired output and don't need access dates. (Of course if you do have evidence that there should be an access date, it may be useful to contact the package author - the documentation should tell you where to complain.)

Comment: @moewe  Well the journal editor said I needed them, so yes, I do!   Good idea about contacting the package author.  I know Joseph Wright is active here...so...@josephwright, what do you think?

Comment: Usually you can't ping people here if they haven't commented already (not sure if this is different for moderators, though). I suggest you log the feature request at https://github.com/josephwright/achemso/issues.